# php como hacer que la ultima entrada aparezca arriba de todo en la tabla?

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap

estoy haciendo una Tienda. En la administración de la misma, estoy haciendo una tabla con todas las ventas aprobadas. Es decir, por cada venta realizada, tengo un foreach que me crea un row con los datos de esa venta.
El problema es que necesito que la **ultima venta realizada, aparezca arriba de todo en la tabla**. Como hago eso?

**Si se fijan en la imagen de abajo, en la parte de la "fecha" me agrego la venta mas reciente abajo**

```
    <h2>Estas son tus ventas:</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
        <tr>
            <th>Venta</th>
            <th>Comprador</th>
            <th>Correo</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
                $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblventas`");
                $sentencia->execute();
                $listaVentas=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            ?>
        <?php
        foreach($listaVentas as $venta){ ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $venta['ID_VENTA']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $venta['Correo']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $venta['Correo']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $venta['Fecha']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $venta['status']?></td>
                <td>$<?php echo $venta['Total']?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ordena la consulta por el campo fecha `DESC`

Comment: Gracias !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h2>Estas son tus ventas:</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <tr>
        <th>Venta</th>
        <th>Comprador</th>
        <th>Correo</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
            $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblventas` ORDER BY `fecha` DESC");
            $sentencia->execute();
            $listaVentas=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        ?>
    <?php
    foreach($listaVentas as $venta){ ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $venta['ID_VENTA']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $venta['Correo']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $venta['Correo']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $venta['Fecha']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $venta['status']?></td>
            <td>$<?php echo $venta['Total']?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```